# Stopping chromium from completing a partial server name?

Tags: google-chrome

This is a pretty annoying thing for me when I try to access an web site on the intranet. Say we have a server called foo. So the url is just `http://wiki`. Chromium tries to be smart and resolve `http://www.wiki.com` but couldn't find it or worse find a different page on the wild internet.

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Well you could scroll down to `www.wiki.com` and press `Shift+Del` to remove it from the suggestion list, but it might add it back the next time you visit `wiki.com`. In addition, you could simply press the slash key after the sever name: `wiki/` That will cancel the suggestion. In fact, if you use the real name enough times, it *should* suggest that automatically and before the other one.